# Fourth order IMEX Runge-Kutta method

Tags: reference-request, time-integration, runge-kutta, operator-splitting

I am looking for the Butcher tableau of a fourth order accurate Runge-Kutta method with IMEX splitting. I have been reading the ''classical'' paper on the subject by [Ascher, Ruuth and Spiteri](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0168-9274(97)00056-1) as well as a number of works that cite this paper (through Google Scholar).

However, in all papers I looked at, only methods of order up to three were given. Since the number of order conditions increases very quickly as the order goes up (in his [slides](http://www.utenti.unife.it/lorenzo.pareschi/talks/imex_slides.pdf), Rascheri states that a general IMEX-RKM has to satisfy 56 conditions), I wonder if such a method has been derived anywhere?

Is there a paper somewhere that states the Butcher tableau for a fourth order IMEX Runge-Kutta method?

Comment: Perhaps the `ESDIRK4` scheme is an example of what you've been looking for? [link](http://fun3d.larc.nasa.gov/papers/carpenter.pdf)

Comment: ESDIRK4 is a DIRK method where the first stage is explicit (zero diagonal entries) and all other diagonal entries are identical. This is not an IMEX method though and therefore not what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes, some confusion there on my part. The `ESDIRK` scheme is actually "one-half" of the (additive) IMEX-RK procedure - namely, the one used to integrate the stiff terms. Non-stiff terms can be integrated with a "traditional" explicit (E) RK scheme. You can find a 4th order additive IMEX (ESDIRK + ERK) method in [this report](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20010075154.pdf). Hope this proves more useful than my 1st comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the work of Kennedy and Carpenter (mentioned already by @GoHokies) is still the definitive study on this topic.  [The journal paper can be found here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168927402001381); for some reason Google Scholar only provides links to the technical report.  It includes methods of up to fifth order that are optimized for a range of properties relevant to convection-diffusion-reaction problems.  Some of the fourth-order methods are compared with fully-implicit methods in [this follow-up work](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02728987).

One more fourth-order -- and low-storage -- IMEX method can be found in [this 2013 paper of Cavaglieri et. al.](http://arc.aiaa.org/doi/pdf/10.2514/6.2013-3094).

One comment regarding the order conditions: while it is true that the number of them grows very rapidly for IMEX methods, this number is much smaller if a few simplifying assumptions are invoked -- for instance, if the abscissas are identical.

Comment: Wonderful, that is what I was looking for! Thanks, David.

Comment: If someone else wants to use the method, you may copy and paste the coefficients from PETsC: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-3.2/src/ts/impls/arkimex/arkimex.c -- this avoids having to putting in all those endless integers by hand :)